# Проверка валидности задаваемого пользователем пути к новому файлу

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

Пользователь вводит строку, в которой будет путь для нового файла. Необходимо проверить строку на длину (<256 символов) и на отсутствие запрещённых символов.
Существует ли метод(ы) в стандартных библиотеках, или в MVVM-Light Toolkit? Или же всё-таки придётся городить собственные велосипеды?

Comment: [Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars?view=netframework-4.8), [Path.GetInvalidPathChars](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 2):

А зачем что-то заранее проверять (тем-более, что проверка неправильная)? Пытайтесь создать файл и анализируйте код ошибки

Comment: Зачем анализировать ошибку, если можно её не допустить?

Comment: @SemKey Нельзя. При задании UNC путей ограничение MAX_PATH не применяется. На создание файла может не хватить прав. Может отсутствовать каталог сохранения (причем, он может пропасть после проверки). Правила валидации могут поменяться. Отдайте все системе и анализируйте ошибку